# MySQL возвращает ASCII, а должен UTF-8 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, кодировка

На локальном хосте такого нету: запрос->ответ в виде массива с кодировкой UTF-8. Но когда закинул на [byet host](https://byet.host), все кириллические символы превратились в знаки вопросов (все таблицы в кодировке UTF-8). Я сразу понял, что проблема в кодировке, и узнал что при запросе в базу, она возваращает ответ в кодировке ASCII. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите кодировку после соединения с базой.

ООП:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf-8');
```

Процедурка:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf-8');
```

Подробнее https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php